# Modal placed in HTML doesn't pop up when trigger on first load on Angular. But if browser refresh it works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-material

### HELLO THIS IS MY CODE IN HTML ANGULAR.

```
<div id="confirmModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content" id="confirmModal_Content">
          TEST TEST
        </div>
</div>
```

---

AND THIS IS MY CODE ON THE COMPONENT

```
onTriggerCreateForAll(value:boolean){
   $('#confirmModal').modal('open');
}
```

---

MY QUESTION IS WHY DOES MY MODAL DOESN'T SHOW WHEN I CLICK THE BUTTON ON THE VERY FIRST LOAD? BUT WHEN I REFRESH MY BROWSER AND CLICK AGAIN MY MODAL SHOWS. ANYONE HELP ME?

Comment: May I know from where you are calling onTriggerCreateForAll() function ?

Comment: @GaneshThorat it is on the same component with the html

Comment: It would be nice if you can host somewhere and share the link e.g plunker, stackblitz etc